# C# get all parent directories from a path up to a point?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a listbox in WPF that automatically gets the FullName of the files listed within the box then will Add those files to a Zip under their specific folder.

For example:

C:\ProgramFiles\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\file.txt

I need to be able to Zip it into its folder up to a specific folder, such as only

\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\file.txt

How could I do this? I've tried getting the Parent directory, but it only returns the directory the file is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the DirectoryInfo object to get the parent up the chain as far as you need to.  If you want to get a the parent directory three levels up you can do something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\ProgramFiles\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\file.txt");
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            di = di.Parent;
        }
```

Obviously, you can change how you stop your traversal to meet your exact need.  After you have the DirectoryInfo object where you need it then you  can do what you need.  I'm assuming you will need either the full path or to use the Directory object.  To get the full path use FullName property.  If for example you wanted all the files in the directory you could do the following:

```
 string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(di.FullName);
```

Comment: Would this be possible with paths that would require X amount of specification, I mean is it possible to get all parent folder names up to everything but C:\ProgramFiles. Like file1.txt would need to go to Folder1, while file2.txt would need to go only to Folder2, but you wouldn't necessarily know how far it would need to go as new paths are added. (The program im making is a autopatch .zip maker, that compares an old file list to a new one, and zips the new files up for a patch.)If you understand what im trying to say.

Comment: In that scenario do you know what you want to consider your root folder?  If so then its just a matter of using a while loop instead of a for and terminating until you get to the path you consider your root path.  So it'd be like: while(di.FullName != @"C:\ProgramFiles"){ di = di.Parent;}.  Does that get you what you want or am I misunderstanding something? Or you do you not know your root directory?  If so that obviously won't work.

Answer (score 5):

```
    private static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> GetAllParentDirectories(DirectoryInfo directoryToScan)
    {
        Stack<DirectoryInfo> ret = new Stack<DirectoryInfo>();
        GetAllParentDirectories(directoryToScan, ref ret);
        return ret;
    }

    private static void GetAllParentDirectories(DirectoryInfo directoryToScan, ref Stack<DirectoryInfo> directories)
    {
        if (directoryToScan == null || directoryToScan.Name == directoryToScan.Root.Name) 
            return;

        directories.Push(directoryToScan);
        GetAllParentDirectories(directoryToScan.Parent, ref directories);
    }
```